# Android Multi Window (Free-Form Mode) Resize Events

Tags: android, multi-window

Stating an application with multi-window mode like below.

```
  private  void startApplication() {
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.comisotest2"); 
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK );


    Rect rect = new Rect(500, 300, 100, 0);

    ActivityOptions activityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
    ActivityOptions bounds = options.setLaunchBounds(rect);

    startActivity(intent,bounds.toBundle());
}
```

I want to handle open window resize events. and I added onConfigurationChanged method.

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Toast.makeText(this, "newConfig.screenHeightDp:"+Integer.toString(newConfig.screenHeightDp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "newConfig.screenWidthDp:"+Integer.toString(newConfig.screenWidthDp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        Toast.makeText(this, "LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

onConfigurationChanged handler is not calling.

I there any way handle all windows resize changes ?

Comment: I think it is only a configuration change if the resize is substantial. There may be other listeners, though, perhaps on `Window`, that you could use.

Comment: I also tried this listener getWindow().getDecorView().addOnLayoutChangeListener...
But this listener in caller application main window. I can't find anyting to add listener started external app activity.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not notice that you are launching a third-party activity. AFAIK, you have no way to know if some other app's window gets resized.

Comment: Is there any way to access third-party activity window ?
I'm search android source code.
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java

Comment: I hope not, for privacy and security reasons.